# Convert True False in column to Boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on Chicago crimes dataset and having trouble with the Arrest column. It says True or False but those are strings, not boolean entries. I tried several things I found on this website but it hasn't fixed it.

```py
test = test['Arrest'].map({'False':False, 'True':True})
```

This just made everything in the dataset True across all columns.

I also tried a for loop though I'm not sure I got it right.

```py
for i in test['Arrest']:
    if i=='True':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I also found a suggestion for a similar problem. This was the code suggested

```py
def str_to_bool(s):
    if s == 'True':
         return True
    elif s == 'False':
         return False
    else:
         raise ValueError
```

But I find that very confusing and not quite applicable either

So for a minimal working example, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to present it:

```py
crimes2012 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Chicago Dataset\\Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv", header=0)
primary = crimes2012[['Primary Type','Arrest']].copy()
test=primary.groupby(['Primary Type','Arrest']).size().sort_values().reset_index(name='Count')
test['Arrest'] = test.Arrest.map(pd.eval)
```

Comment: `.map({'False':False, 'True':True})` works for me. Are you sure you used `map` and not `replace`? You can also use `.map(pd.eval)`.

Comment: `def str_to_bool(s): return s == "True"`

Comment: maybe create minimal working example so we could run it.

Comment: .map({'False':False, 'True':True}) isn't working for me at all but .map(pd.eval) worked I think!

Comment: You're missing an `['Arrest']` in `test = test['Arrest'].map({'False':False, 'True':True})`

Comment: `.map()` works for me - but I have to assing it back to the same column `test['Arrest'] = test['Arrest'].map(...)`. If I test `print(test['Arrest'].dtype)` then it shows `bool`

Comment: so for minimal working example: `test = pd.DataFrame({
    "Arrest": ["False","False","False"],
    "X": ["True","False","True"],
})`. I forgot `import pandas as pd`

Comment: I tried it again the dtype is object

Comment: `test[['Arrest', 'X']] = test[['Arrest', 'X']].applymap(pd.eval)` for multiple columns.

Comment: check all values  in column - if you have value(s) different than `"True"`, `"False"` then `.dtype` can't be `bool`

Comment: I think the suggestion of .map(pd.eval) worked, it certainly returned a bool type for Arrests. I don't know how to mark it as the answer but its working right now

Comment: @coldspeed I created column "X" to confirm that  `test['Arrest'].map()` can't change values in other columns :)

Comment: `test['Arrest'] = test['Arrest'].map()` don't forget to assign it back...

Comment: ask coldspeed to create real answer below and then you can mark it as accepted

Comment: No worries, I've marked the question as a duplicate of another one. If you are looking for something to upvote, feel free to read some of [my answers here](https://github.com/Coldsp33d/stackoverflow-pandas-canonicals) ;)